# Try to load image with Highgui.imread (OpenCV + Android)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I try to load an image:

```
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(root, "image.gif");
    Mat m = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
    if(file.exists()){
        showToast("Height: " + m.height() + " Width: " + m.width());
    }
```

But the size=0 (height/width).

Comment: @karlphillip Android, Environment.getExternal, ctor syntax, static calls use . syntax instead of :: and no pointers all tell the tale of Java

Comment: @ChHaupt You should look into JavaCV for android development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the file exists doesn't mean that OpenCV was able to read its contents.

What you should be doing instead is:

```
Mat m = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
if (img.data)
{
     showToast("Height: " + m.height() + " Width: " + m.width());
}
else
{
     // print error and abort execution
}
```

There is a big note at the end of the docs of [`imread()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29) that states the following:

> The function determines the type of an image by the content, not by the file extension.

You should check the docs before proceeding. Make sure you can write a simple OpenCV application that loads and displays an image from the disk before adventuring on more complex stuff.

Comment: Okay. I try to load a *.gif but wasnt supported. A *.bmp works.

Comment: Your if condition should probably be switched to `if (m != null)`. The data attribute does not exist in java afaik.

Comment: Or:       if (!m.empty())

Answer (score -2):

try to use

```
IplImage orgImage= cvLoadImage(fileName);
```

It is working on JavaCV wrapper. But i don't no will it work on pure OpenCV.

Comment: The function cvLoadImage does not exist in OpenCV for Android and the class IplImage isnt implemented/wrapped.

Comment: Those are available on JavaCV - a Wrapper to OpenCV

Comment: I know the JavaCV but the installation is tricky... And i definitely want to use the OpenCV for Android wrapper :)

Comment: I think it is simply to use JavaCV, than OpenCV with Android.

Comment: JavaCV for android, you don't have to install any thing. Just set of jar files and set of .so files need to be placed on your lib folder

Comment: I tryed to "install" JavaCV for a another project with the tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) but it dosnt work. For my current project i have to use the OpenCV wrapper.

Comment: for Android projects you don't have to install any thing. But for Windows projects you have to install OpenCV. I have been working on both types of projects. If you need any help regarding JavaCV i can help you.

Comment: Okay. My problem with JavaCV: (http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=206 )

Comment: try to use cvCreateImage() to create an Image

Comment: cvCreateImage() is a function which class? I cant found cvCreateImage(). I guess i get the same exception, because i tryed ohter function with similar error.

Comment: It is a native method at 'opencv_core' class