# Read array of images from external directory into MAT objects in android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, mat

How do i read array of images stored in SDcard to a array of MAT object ? i want to do similar imread like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752556/try-to-load-image-with-highgui-imread-opencv-android) post, but for array of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File directoyOfMatFiles; // it points to the directory that contains mat files
File[] contentOfDirectoyOfMatFiles = directoyOfMatFiles.listFiles();
ArrayList<Mat> mats = new ArrayList<Mat>();
for (File f : contentOfDirectoyOfMatFiles) {
   Mat m = Highgui.imread(f.getAbsolutePath());
   mats.add(m);
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot